# Add-PSSnapin not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I'm using the cmdlet Get-SPWeb in my script but not working so I used Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell to resolve the problem. Eventhough I still get an error when I use Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell command here is the error msg :

- Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershe 
  ll:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ad 
  dPSSnapinCommand
  ```

I'm using powershell ISE version 5 and PnP script.

Please help !
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can do anything with PowerShell ISE, you need to make sure that

(1) You are running SharePoint Management Shell or PowerShell ISE as an Administrator

and

(2) that the execution policy is set in such a way that you can execute scripts.

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Open SharePoint Management Shell and run as an admin:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

[image]

2.If you get **RemoteSigned, Unrestricted or Bypass** you can safely continue.RemoteSigned means that you can't run scripts that are downloaded from the another server or the internet unless it is signed. If you download files to run in PowerShell ISE, set the execution policy to unrestricted, like this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

3.If all works as expected, run PowerShell ISE as an Administrator. Then try to load the SharePoint.PowerShell with the following:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
```

[image]

4.When that has loaded, try another command, such as

```
Get-SPManagedAccount
```

[image]

5.If you receive no error messages, then you have SharePoint.PowerShell loaded. If not, run

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
```